# Sign up sheet for tickets

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, permissions, list-form

Background: Our HR office loans out 12 Zoo Passes to anyone who wants them. (They have to bring them back when they are done)

Is there a way to automate this in SharePoint?
The idea would be: They could look at the monthly list and see when the tickets are available, and then reserve the tickets on the calendar. Users need to put their phone number down in case administrators need to get a hold of them.

The caveat is that users should not be able to see other users phone numbers. And the system should somehow prevent users from signing up if there are not enough tickets.

Any thought!? 
-A frantic intern...

Answer (score 0):

This is very generic requirement and can be easily met with SharePoint.

See below:

create all the required field in the registration list and allow the users to submit via the list form. maintain a seperate  configuration list which has some lookup based on event name or datetime.

Now, create a custom event handler which validated the booked tickets with the number mapped in the config list. Show a message and cancel the action if the registrations are over booked.

SharePoint list offers the admins to set the options only to view and allow their own items for editing for the users as OOTB permissions management.

if you have complex validations during the registration process then you may consider options like infopath or custom layouts page based on the requirements.